# Running R script and global variable overriding with <<- from cron

Tags: cron, variable, variable-substitution, r

I have a R script that works just fine when I run it from RStudio. However, once I schedule it through `cron` under user RStudio only with home directory (`/home/rstudio`), it halts at the very step I need to read a file from /home/rstudio directory only. 
My cron looks like the following where the R code runs fines when sourced in through RStudio:

```
44 13  * * * Rscript appsFlyer.R >> cron_debug_appsflyer.txt
```

In R code `appFlyier.R`, one of the lines of code where `<<-` overrides a global variable from local scope:

```
data <<- read.csv('/home/rstudio/appFlyersInstallReport', header=TRUE , sep = ",")
```

The script stops executing right here without any errors and does not even move to the next line. It just stops here. 
Why is that? How do I fix it? 
It happens only when I run it through cron for RStudio user.

Similarly, if I had a `write.table` statement here to write data in local file, it would again get stuck at the very line.

Comment: What is this line suppposed to do? Is it populating `read.csv` file?

Comment: I am just reading the file and storing the read file in a variable called data to get some values from the file but I am not really able to read it in first place when I run it through cron. The script just stops here. @user1700494

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rscript, but is it possible that it's influenced by an environment variable (that is getting set interactively but not via cron)?

Comment: Shouldn't the line be `data <- read.csv(...)` with just one `<` instead of 2? I am not an expert in R but I do some implementation work for data scientists in my firm so I could be wrong, yet I have never seen the `<<-` operator.

Comment: <<- operator is used to override the value of a global variable from local scope. It indeed is permissions issue

Comment: @Simran Have you managed to solve the issue? I think this is really a basic thing. Have you looked permissions and ownership? - - What is your OS? What is your R version? What is your cron version?